# What causes `M-S-t` (meta + shift + t) key binding not to take?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, aquamacs

By default, `C-S-t` and `M-S-t` are both unbound in my Emacs. Hence, when I press them, they are translated into `C-t` and `M-t`. Fine, but I want to use them for a tweak on the original function, and therefore put these lines in my `.emacs`:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-t") 'transpose-chars-backward)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-S-t") 'transpose-words-backward)
```

The functions there are my own, and work fine when called via `M-x`.

This works for `C-S-t`, but not for `M-S-t` which still gets translated to `M-t`. The message on `C-h k M-S-t` confirms this.

It's not that it's impossible to configure `M-S-` combinations in general, because `M-q` and `M-S-q` do different things.

What causes this inconsistency and how can I get around it?

I'm running Aquamacs on Mac OS X 10.9.5.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you have two different ways to do what you want:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-T") 'transpose-words-backwards)
(global-set-key [(meta shift t)] 'transpose-words-backwards)
```

I am not sure what causes the `(kbd "M-S-t")` working differently from `(kbd "C-S-t")`, btw.  Time ago I became an adept to vector notation (`[(meta shift t)]`) as I find it more predictable (I always get it right the first time, and with `kbd` notation sometimes I needed a couple of tries).

Comment: `C-h k M-S-t` gives "M-t (translated from M-T) ...".  In my experience, `C-h k` always tells you exactly what to give `kbd`.

Comment: @jpkotta I take it your experience of Aquamacs is limited. ;)  what I got was “⌥T (translated from ⌥⇧T)”. I'm not going to explore whether I could actually use that as kbd arguments.

Comment: @njlarsson You're right, I've never used Aquamacs.  That sounds like a bug though; you should report it.