# Why the key binding M-S-t fails while C-S-t works?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I got the question from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38140280/what-causes-m-s-t-meta-shift-t-key-binding-not-to-take), it seems we can't bind <kbd>shift</kbd> with <kbd>meta</kbd> like `M-S-t` (always translated to `M-t`), but we can do it with <kbd>control</kbd> like `C-S-t` (works as `C-T`).

As the accepted answer said, we can use `M-T` instead, but why we can't use it with <kbd>meta</kbd>? Does Emacs just ignore `shift` when used with <kbd>meta</kbd>?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Emacs ignores `S-` for letters when Ctrl is not also used.

i.e. it's nothing to do with Meta in particular; the same thing applies to the other non-Ctrl modifiers (and indeed without other modifiers -- you also can't bind to plain `S-t`).

The justification may be that Ctrl keys are the only case where an explicit shift modifier is *needed* for letters:

`(emacs) Modifier Keys` says

```
The default key bindings in Emacs are set up so that modified
alphabetical characters are case-insensitive.  In other words, ‘C-A’
does the same thing as ‘C-a’, and ‘M-A’ does the same thing as ‘M-a’.
This concerns only alphabetical characters, and does not apply to
“shifted” versions of other keys; for instance, ‘C-@’ is not the same as
‘C-2’.

   A <Control>-modified alphabetical character is always considered
case-insensitive: Emacs always treats ‘C-A’ as ‘C-a’, ‘C-B’ as ‘C-b’,
and so forth.  The reason for this is historical.

   For all other modifiers, you can make the modified alphabetical
characters case-sensitive when you customize Emacs.  For instance, you
could make ‘M-a’ and ‘M-A’ run different commands.
```

By my recollection terminals do not distinguish case for control characters, so I would speculate that the "historical" reasons are related to that.

It would be reasonable for this to at least be documented in the manual. You may wish to `M-x report-emacs-bug` to suggest such an improvement, if no relevant bug exists at present.

Note that the Shift modifier *can* be used with non-letter keys, with or without other modifiers. `M-S-SPC` is a recognised sequence, for example.

Comment: As noted in https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/55142/454 Emacs doesn't actually *ignore* `S-t` (for example), but it does recognise it as something other than `T` -- `(kbd "S-t")` is `[33554548]`, which is not what Emacs sees when you type Shift+t, so any binding for `S-t` will not be used in normal circumstances.  Evaluating `(execute-kbd-macro (kbd "S-t"))` would invoke it, however.