# How to set shift shortcut on emacs

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings

I want to set a shift combo shortcut for my custom function like this.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "S-u") 'my-custom-function)
```

But when I complete this and click "shift + u", it report "U is undefined" error.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/38180797/324105

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just `(global-set-key "U" #'my-custom-function)`

Setting that binding will make it hard to type normally though, you will need to quoted insert every time you want to type a capital "U" unless you have done some modifications to your keys.

Comment: It might be have some problem when I type `U` literal, but always thanks